# Kerberos authentication with python

Tags: python, security, kerberos

I need to write a script in python to check a webpage, which is protected by kerberos. Is there any possibility to do this from within python and how? The script is going to be deployed on a linux environment with python 2.4.something installed.

dertoni

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that `python-krbV` and most Linux distributions also have a `python-kerberos` package. For example, Debian has one of the same name. Here's the documentation on [it](http://packages.debian.org/testing/python/python-kerberos)

Extract from link:

> "This Python package is a high-level wrapper for Kerberos (GSSAPI)
>   operations. The goal is to avoid having to build a module that wraps
>   the entire Kerberos.framework, and instead offer a limited set of
>   functions that do what is needed for client/server Kerberos
>   authentication based on http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4559.txt. "

Comment: This is the method I've used in the past. I thought it was ugly but it does work.

Comment: Sorry hernan, I am relatively new, so I don't have a better idea. All the best.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on using the python kerberos module: https://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html